# write to terminal via bash script

Tags: bash, terminal

I have to run some hundreds of simulations and scan the output file for a certain variable. In order to run the program, I need to write

```
$SIMPLESIM/simplesim-3.0/sim-outorder -config ../../config/tmp.cfg bzip2_base.i386-m32-gcc42-nn dryer.jpg
```

to the terminal, where tmp.cfg is the config file I will be modifying for each simulation. Running this outputs a file in which I named via tmp.cfg. This obviously works when I literally type it into terminal, however, in bash script, running this command gives me the error

```
simplesim-3.0/sim-outorder no such file or directory
```

I believe it has to do with the $ symbol? Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you define SIMPLESIM in your script?

Comment: I dont follow. What do you mean by define? When I type the above command in the terminal, it works perfectly, but not when I run it as a line in my bash file. I am not even sure what the $SIMPLESIM part even means, I assume it has to do with file path?

Comment: just do echo $SIMPLESIM in terminal, what is value you are getting say /usr/tmp, do SIMPLESIM=/usr/tmp in the bash script

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much. So I guess $SIMPLESIM was some sort of variable/shortcut I was using and all I had to do was define it.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling any command its path must be defined in $PATH variable or you have to manually give the complete path to invoke it. 
So define SIMPLESIM in script to the path, like SIMPLESIM=/usr/bin , this /usr/bin is for reference only.To know the path do echo $SIMPLESIM in terminal and see the path
and call the command $SIMPLESIM/simplesim-3.0/sim-outorder -config ../../config/tmp.cfg bzip2_base.i386-m32-gcc42-nn dryer.jpg